# Using private jquery with RequireJS - issue after optimisation

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization, requirejs

I'm putting together a framework using requireJS with a CDN version of jQuery (as is now the recommended approach) and having some issue when optimizing the code.  The output is namespaced and I'm specifying that each module use a private version of jquery as outlined in the documentation:

```
require.config({
    // Add this map config in addition to any baseUrl or
    // paths config you may already have in the project.
    map: {
      // '*' means all modules will get 'jquery-private'
      // for their 'jquery' dependency.
      '*': { 'jquery': 'jquery-private' },

      // 'jquery-private' wants the real jQuery module
      // though. If this line was not here, there would
      // be an unresolvable cyclic dependency.
      'jquery-private': { 'jquery': 'jquery' }
    }
});

// and the 'jquery-private' module, in the
// jquery-private.js file:
define(['jquery'], function (jq) {
    return jq.noConflict( true );
});
```

The problem I'm seeing after optimization is that "jq" is undefined in the "jquery-private.js" file.

Any ideas?  I've tried setting jq = $ but that seems to destroy the global.

Thanks.

Comment: It works fine if you take away the map config and don't try to make it a private version?

Comment: Yes, it works fine without the map config

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is what I did to get the [jQuery CDN & optimization sample](https://github.com/requirejs/example-jquery-cdn) linked from the [RequireJS jQuery Instructions page](http://www.requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html) to work with the [Mapping Modules to use noConflict](http://www.requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html#noconflictmap) section that you pasted in your original question.

1 - Forked the [sample](https://github.com/requirejs/example-jquery-cdn)

2 - Created file `www/js/lib/jquery-private.js` with this content

```
define(['jquery'], function (jq) {
    return jq.noConflict( true );
});
```

3 - Modified `www/js/app.js` to paste the `map` section so the `require.config` now looks like this:

```
requirejs.config({
    "baseUrl": "js/lib",
    "paths": {
      "app": "../app",
      "jquery": "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min"
    },
    map: {
      '*': { 'jquery': 'jquery-private' },
      'jquery-private': { 'jquery': 'jquery' }
    }    
});
```

4 - Modified `www/js/app/main.js` to use `jqlocal` instead of `$` (just to prove to myself that it's not the global jQuery:

```
define(["jquery", "jquery.alpha", "jquery.beta"], function(jqlocal) {
    jqlocal(function() {
        jqlocal('body').alpha().beta();
    });
});
```

5 - Changed to the `tools` folder and ran:

```
node r.js -o build.js
```

6 - Changed to the `www-build` folder that was created and ran `servedir` (doesn't really matter what web server but that's what I use for dev)

7 - Browsed to the local address & port number of the app (in my case `http://localhost:8000/app.html`) and saw:

> Alpha is Go!
>
> Beta is Go!

You can see the end result [here](https://github.com/explunit/example-jquery-cdn)

Comment: In case it's not obvious, that paths value of 'jquery' is vital in the RequireJS docs. I ran into this myself and beat my head against a wall for about half an hour. If it's not there, jq will be UNDEFINED in the jquery-private.js module.

Answer (score 0):

To get this working I changed the way I was using Require (possibly how I should have been doing it all along).  This information might prove useful to others, so I thought I'd put it out there.

Previously I was specifying any dependencies in the defined module:

```
define( [ "dep1", "dep2", "jquery" ], function( var1, var2, jq ) {
```

This worked fine initially, but failed when optimized.  I moved the dependencies to the require function call including this module and it then started to work OK both pre and post optimisation, with jquery being used privately:

```
require( [ 'jquery', 'dep1', 'dep2' ], function( jq, var1, var2 ) {
    formValidator.formValidationInit( jq( el ) );
});
```

I wouldn't have thought this would have made a difference, but it seemed too.

It is also worth noting that I had to change the jquery-private file as it was still throwing up an issue concerning "jq" not being defined.  I am now setting jq equal to the global $ and returning it so it can be used pivately:

```
define(['jquery'], function () {
    var jq = $;
    return jq.noConflict( true );
});
```

Comment: This is the absolutely wrong way to use requireJS. Instead of defining a module, all you're doing is declaring a require load -- might as well not use requirejs. 'jq' is UNDEFINED probably because you're missing the 'jquery' attribute in the paths in the config (see explunit's answer). This piece of non-trivial information is missing in the requireJS documentation.

Comment: Thanks Robert - It didn't feel right, but I was having issues compiling the code and using private jquery.  After reading this, I have gone back and refactored my code and it's working as expected.

Essentially I removed the modules from the require calls back into the module definitions.  Although missing from my initial post, I did have the jquery path listed, but have also seen that this trivial info is missing from the documentation.

Thanks again for your responses