# Jquery no Conflict with require js issue

Tags: jquery, angularjs, requirejs

I defined the jquery no conflict approach as defined here [Using private jquery with RequireJS - issue after optimisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17615594/using-private-jquery-with-requirejs-issue-after-optimisation)

But after which i load my page with additional configurations like these.

```
config.paths.jqueryLayout = ["scripts/jquery.layout-1.3.0"];
config.shim.jqueryLayout = {deps: ['jquery']};

config.paths.jqueryUi = ["scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.min"];
config.shim.jqueryUi = {deps: ['jquery']};
```

Now after adding the no conflict to true ..i am getting all these errors as below, not sure why ? Please can someone help ?

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ui' of undefined jquery-ui-1.10.min.js:5
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined jquery.event.drag-2.0.min.js:6
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function bootstrap.min.js:6
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'extend' of undefined slick.pager.js:146
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'extend' of undefined slick.core.js:9
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function highcharts.js:30
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'extend' of undefined slick.cellselectionmodel.js:3
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'CellSelectionModel' of undefined
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach linked from that question: [Mapping Modules to use noConflict](http://www.requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html#noconflictmap), says this:

> If **all of your modules** (including any third party jQuery plugins or library code that depend on jQuery) are AMD compatible and you want to avoid...

But you appear to be using several jQuery plugins that are not AMD compatible (i.e. you needed the `shim` config) so I don't think you will be able to use the noConflict approach.